# How to show this function is differentiable everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto x |x|.$

I plotted this function with Wolfram, and I see it is smooth everywhere so I figure it must be everywhere differentiable. I wanted to prove it using the definition. We have $$ \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \frac{(x+h) | x + h| - x | x|}{h}. $$ I'm not sure how to find the limit of this quotient for $h \to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function can also be defined as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2 &\text{if }x>0,\\-x^2 &\text{if }x<0,\\0 &\text{if }x=0.\end{cases}$$
So it's differentiable if $x\ne0$. The only problem is at $x=0$. For  that we have to calculate the limit of the rate of variation at $0$.

- $\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}h=\dfrac{h^2}h=h$ if $h>0$;
- $\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}h=-\dfrac{h^2}h=-h$ if $h<0$.

In both cases, the rate of variations tends to $0$ as $h$ tends to $0$, so 
$f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\left.f\right|_{\mathbb{R^-}} = - x^2$ and  $\left.f\right|_{\mathbb{R^+}} = x^2$, so you only need to check at $x=0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $x>0$, you can take $h$ small enough to have $x+h>0$. If $x<0$, you can take $h$ small enough to have $x+h<0$ and if $x=0$, then it's obvious.

Comment: So do we have $f'(x) = 2x$ then?

Comment: $$f'(x)= \begin{cases}2x&x>0\\-2x&x<0\\ 0&x=0\end{cases}$$